# How to make the window buttons rectangular in Classic theme in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, themes

This is how the buttons look after installing a third-party color schemes to Windows registry:

[image]

This is Windows Classic theme engine with Themes service and DWM turned off.

How it is possible to make the buttons appear non-square?